# How to create a connected graph in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I  want to create a connected graph in `IPython` notebook through `NetworkX`. Previously, I use

```
erdos_renyi_graph
```

to generate a random graph, but I never get a connected graph, I want to use this graph to prove that my graph is a small world network. But the unconnected graph's average shortest path cannot be calculated. So please tell me how to generate a connected graph through `NetworkX`.

Comment: option 1) take the largest component of the Erdos-Renyi graph.
option 2) Read the original papers on small-world networks and you'll have a better idea of how one shows that a graph is a small-world network.

Comment: [Here's one approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961881/9698684) adapting the Erdős-Rényi graph generator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you didn't mention the exact parameters of your graph I want to suggest playing with the probability of creating edges.
The following networkx function allows you to provide a probability (p) for an edge to exist in the graph.

```
erdos_renyi_graph(n, p, seed=None, directed=False)
```

As an example:

```
G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(500, 0.5, seed=123, directed=False)
```

provides you a fully connected graph.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of [graph generators for `NetworkX`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generators.html) defined, you can use not only the [`erdos_renyi_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.erdos_renyi_graph.html#networkx.generators.random_graphs.erdos_renyi_graph) (which can be adjusted to nearly connected by second parameter):

[Social Networks](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.social) graphs for you:

- `karate_club_graph()` - Return [Zachary’s Karate club graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.social.karate_club_graph.html#networkx.generators.social.karate_club_graph).
- `davis_southern_women_graph()` - Return [Davis Southern women social network](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.social.davis_southern_women_graph.html#networkx.generators.social.davis_southern_women_graph).
- `florentine_families_graph()`- Return [Florentine families graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.social.florentine_families_graph.html#networkx.generators.social.florentine_families_graph).

[Community graphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.community):

- `caveman_graph(l, k)` - Returns a [caveman graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.caveman_graph.html#networkx.generators.community.caveman_graph) of `l` cliques of size `k`.
- `connected_caveman_graph(l, k)` - Returns a [connected caveman graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.connected_caveman_graph.html#networkx.generators.community.connected_caveman_graph) of `n` cliques of size `k`.
- `relaxed_caveman_graph(l, k, p[, seed, directed])` - Return a [relaxed caveman graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.relaxed_caveman_graph.html#networkx.generators.community.relaxed_caveman_graph).
- `random_partition_graph(sizes, p_in, p_out[, ...])` - Return the [random partition graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.random_partition_graph.html#networkx.generators.community.random_partition_graph) with a partition of sizes.
- `planted_partition_graph(l, k, p_in, p_out[, ...])` - Return the [planted `l`-partition graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.planted_partition_graph.html#networkx.generators.community.planted_partition_graph).
- `gaussian_random_partition_graph(n, s, v, ...)` - Generate a [Gaussian random partition graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.generators.community.gaussian_random_partition_graph.html#networkx.generators.community.gaussian_random_partition_graph).
- `ring_of_cliques`

and so on.