# Fully connect an unconnected bi-partite graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62893202/fully-connect-an-unconnected-graph-in-networkx) question, with a small difference. Namely, I am already given a graph G, which is a bi-partite graph, meaning that there exist two sets of vertices, set U and set I, and the connection could only exist between a node from the set U and a node from the set I.

I want to extend this unconnected graph by making it connected and still bi-partite, and I also want that the probability of a new edge (when extending the graph with edges) is proportional to the nodes degrees (i.e., higher probability that an edge links two nodes of large degrees). The code that I would like to extend:

```
import random
from itertools import combinations, groupby

components = dict(enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)))
components_combs = combinations(components.keys(), r=2)

for _, node_edges in groupby(components_combs, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    node_edges = list(node_edges)
    random_comps = random.choice(node_edges)
    source = random.choice(list(components[random_comps[0]]))
    target = random.choice(list(components[random_comps[1]]))
    G.add_edge(source, target)
```

Comment: @yatu Maybe you could help...

Comment: Hi! Could you please add a definition for a small example graph G at the top of your code?

Comment: The code you've found is already pretty good. The only thing you need to change is the way `source` and `target` are chosen. Instead of choosing `source` among all vertices from the source component, choose it only from the vertices that are both from the source component and set U. Then instead of choosing `target` among all vertices from the target component, choose it only from the vertices that are both from the target component and set I.

Comment: @Stef Thanks. How about incorporating probabilities of new links that are dependent on node degrees?

Comment: Then instead of `random.choice`, use `random.choices`, with the node degrees as the optional weights parameter. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences

Comment: @Stef Thanks! You may (if you want) write the above as your answer and I will accept it.